# Opencv SLIC code

Tags: c++, opencv

```
    #include <opencv/cv.h>
    #include <opencv/highgui.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>  
    #include <vector>
    #include <float.h>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;
    #include "slic.h"
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
/* Load the image and convert to Lab colour space. */

    for(int i=1;i<=1863;i++)
  {
        stringstream ss;           
    ss<<i;                      
    string si = "/home/me/Desktop/dataset/" + ss.str() + ".jpg";
    Mat image;
    image=imread(si,1);
IplImage *lab_image;
IplImage *image2;
lab_image=cvCreateImage(cvSize(image.cols,image.rows),8,3);
image2=cvCreateImage(cvSize(image.cols,image.rows),8,3);
IplImage ipltemp=image; 
cvCopy(&ipltemp,lab_image);
cvCopy(&ipltemp,image2);
cvCvtColor(&image, lab_image, CV_BGR2Lab);


/* Yield the number of superpixels and weight-factors from the user. */
int w = image.cols, h = image.rows;
int nr_superpixels = atoi(argv[1]);
int nc = atoi(argv[2]);
double step = sqrt((w * h) / (double) nr_superpixels);


/* Perform the SLIC superpixel algorithm. */
Slic slic;
slic.generate_superpixels(lab_image, step, nc);
slic.create_connectivity(lab_image);


/* Display the contours and show the result. */
slic.display_contours(image2, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
Mat image3(image2);
imshow("result", image3);
cvWaitKey(0);
string ssave1 = "/home/me/Desktop/new_result/" + ss.str()+ ".jpg";
imwrite(ssave1,image3);
//cvSaveImage("/home/me/Desktop/img.jpg", image);
}
}
```

**I got this error:**
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.9-2precise-20140819-1808/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:698: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.9-2precise-20140819-1808/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:698: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat
**I am new to coding in cpp can someone please tell whats wrong?**

Comment: please use opencv's c++ api, not the deprecated c-api. avoid all IplImages, and use cv::Mat consistently

Comment: which SLIC library is that ?

Comment: i got this thing here https://github.com/PSMM/SLIC-Superpixels

Comment: ^^ ... unmaintained since 2 years..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. when working with opencv, be wary of anything containing IplImages. that *must* be outdated and unmaintained
2. get https://github.com/berak/SLIC-Superpixels.git
3. change your code:

--

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>  
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <opencv/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
#include "slic.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /* Yield the number of superpixels and weight-factors from the user. */
    int nr_superpixels = atoi(argv[1]);
    int nc = atoi(argv[2]);


    for(int i=1;i<=1863;i++)
    {
        /* Load the image and convert to Lab colour space. */
        stringstream ss;           
        ss<<i;                      
        string si = "/home/me/Desktop/dataset/" + ss.str() + ".jpg";
        Mat image = imread(si,1);
        Mat lab_image;
        cvtColor(image, lab_image, COLOR_BGR2Lab);

        double step = sqrt((image.total()) / (double) nr_superpixels);

        /* Perform the SLIC superpixel algorithm. */
        Slic slic;
        slic.generate_superpixels(lab_image, step, nc);
        slic.create_connectivity(lab_image);


        /* Display the contours and show the result. */
        slic.display_contours(image2, Vec3b(0,0,255));
        imshow("result", image2);
        waitKey(0);
        string ssave1 = "/home/me/Desktop/new_result/" + ss.str()+ ".jpg";
        imwrite(ssave1,image2);
    }
}
```

Comment: cool there was an error at line 56 in slic.cpp, i am using opencv 2.4.9 with ros hydro..i could solve the issue.

Comment: thanks for the feedback ! hehe, been playing a bit with it since(so line numbers no more match). the error was ?

Comment: been throwing out most of the `vector<vector<>>` things for Mat_, runs like a third faster now here.

Comment: look at the edit i did here at  line 56 here https://github.com/ruthvik92/SLIC-Superpixels/blob/master/slic.cpp there was error regarding accessing values from a vector and i want to label this superpixels can you throw some light on this?

Comment: sorry, i can't see, what you changed (and my version differs significantly now). but i made a test on linux against 2.4.9 , indeed found an error (in a different place). can you either explain a bit more, or try a fresh pull ? (hey, you're my beta-tester now ;)

Comment: at least your repo compiles fine for me.

Comment: i changed `cv::Vec3b colour = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(nc.y, nc.x);' to   

`cv::Vec3b clr = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(nc.y, nc.x);` 

`cv::Scalar colour(clr[0],clr[1],clr[2]);` at all applicable places.

Comment: ah, ok. makes sense. replaced the `vector<vector<>>` thing a version later, but just keep, what makes it run for you ! if i may ask, - what are you trying to do with it ? (just curious..)

Comment: i am trying to make superpixels of a image of a scene and make GMM of of the superpixels on the road. did you find any such projects?? can you throw in some links or sources.